# Why pipes are not working on Powershell for various NodeJS CLI tools?

Tags: node.js, windows, powershell, command-line-interface

I am trying around the following highly used tools:
[prettyjson](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prettyjson)
[prettier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prettier)

For example when I run the following on Powershell:
`echo '{"a": 1}' | prettyjson`

The terminal will just keep waiting for inputs till CTRL+C pressed and it exits with no expected output.

The workaround is to add `.cmd` to the command or just use cmd instead:
`echo '{"a": 1}' | prettyjson.cmd`

Outputs

```yaml
a: 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a known limitation and a pull request is available:
https://github.com/npm/cmd-shim/pull/43